# Class Object cannot be cast to String class - classCastException

Tags: java, generics

```
public class test2<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] data = (T[]) new Object[3];


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        test2<String> t = new test2<String>();
        t.data[0] = (String) "Amar";
        t.data[1] = (String) "Buddi";
        t.data[2] = (String) "puppy";
    }
}
```

I have tried without typecasting also, but getting class cast exception always, can someone let me know what is the right way to use generic here.

Comment: Because casting `Object[]` to `String[]` is not allowed. However, a plain `Object[]` can hold a `String` instance. You would then use the generics with methods to guarantee what is added/retrieved from your `test2` is actually a `T`/`String`, and _not_ provide direct access to the underlying array. This is how the collections api works in many places.

Answer (score 0):

Java generics and arrays don't mix very well.

In this specific example, there isn't a need for generics, and a simple `Object[]` will work just as well:

```
public class test2 {

    Object[] data = new Object[3];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test2 t = new test2();
        t.data[0] = "Amar";
        t.data[1] = "Buddi";
        t.data[2] = "puppy";
    }
}
```

In the case where you do need to use generics for some other reason, using an `ArrayList` rather than an array makes this easy:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test2<T> {

    ArrayList<T> data = new ArrayList<>(3);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test2<String> t = new test2<>();
        t.data.add("Amar");
        t.data.add("Buddi");
        t.data.add("puppy");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, an array can be created by reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class test2<T> {
    T[] data;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public test2(Class<T> clazz) {
        data = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test2<String> t = new test2<>(String.class);
        t.data[0] = "Amar";
        t.data[1] = "Buddi";
        t.data[2] = "puppy";
    }
}
```

See ["Creating a Generic Array in Java"](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generic-array) on Baeldung for a more in depth discussion.